# How much bandwidth does Ventrilo use?

Tags: ventrilo

How much bandwidth does Ventrilo use? If the amount of people matter, then lets say  10 to 15 people on and in the same channel at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ventrilo has several codecs. In your situation, it would be better to have the voice optimize codec running at 24-32 kbps. This is designed for voice only and anything else will get distorted with many artifacts.

If you have the bandwidth, I would suggest that you use 128 kbps/MP3 -- but remember that your voice quality will be affected by your upload bandwidth.

Comment: referring to the mp3, It would probably better to denote the unit as kilobits per second, which is commonly abbreviated as **kbps**, as opposed to kilobytes per second abbrev. as **KB/s**

Comment: 128 kbps MP3 is very extravagant just for voice.